# Rotating an equilateral triangle with a rotation matrix on canvas

Tags: javascript, html

So I am pretty sure that I am derping massively here on the math somewhere, because it checks out on paper.... but... my triangle is rotating right off the page haha. What I am trying to do is rotate an equilateral triangle counter-clockwise forever, where the origin(center of triangle, IE three lines, one from each vertex towards the middle, where they meet is how I am defining the center of the triangle) does not move. So here is my math summary incase there is an error here:

v1(x1,y1),v2(x2,y2),and v3(x3.y3) represent the vertexes in the triangle. First I calculate the center of the triangle: x=(x1+x2+x3)/3, y=(y1+y2+y3)/3. Next I create three new vertices by subtracting the values of the center from each vertex. Then I multiply each new vertex by the rotational matrix for 30 degrees, and add the center to the new rotated vertex.

I tried my best to read over this and make sure that it made sense.

Here is my code:

```js
function calcVerts() {
    var xOrig = (x1 + x2 + x3)/3;
    var yOrig = (y1 + y2 + y3)/3;
    
    x1 -= xOrig;
    x2 -= xOrig;
    x3 -= xOrig;
    y1 -= yOrig;
    y2 -= yOrig;
    y3 -= yOrig; 

    x1 = (x1 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y1);
    y1 = (x1 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y1);
    x2 = (x2 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y2);
    y2 = (x2 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y2);
    x3 = (x3 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);
    y3 = (x4 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);
    
    x1 += xOrig;
    x2 += xOrig;
    x3 += xOrig;
    y1 += yOrig;
    y2 += yOrig;
    y3 += yOrig; 
}
function drawScreen() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height); //clear canvas before each repaint
    
    // the triangle
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(x1, y1);
    context.lineTo(x2, y2);
    context.lineTo(x3, y3);
    context.closePath();
    base++;
    // the outline
    context.lineWidth = 10;
    context.strokeStyle = '#666666';
    context.stroke();
    
    calcVerts();
}

theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
var speed = 5;
var base = 400;
var height = 346.4;
var x1 = base-200;
var x2 = base-400;
var x3 = base;
var y1 = height-346.4;
var y2 = height;
var y3 = height;

function drawLoop() {
    window.setTimeout(drawLoop, 500);
    drawScreen();
}
drawLoop();
```

```html
<div align="center">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

**EDIT1:**
Thanks to Jason catching the typo I am no longer spinning off the page, but instead the triangle is shrinking on each rotation. the edit: `y3 = (x4 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);` to `y3 = (x3 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);`

Comment: Changing this `x4` to `x3` will help: `y3 = (x4 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);` But now the triangle shrinks, so you've got a new problem.

Comment: Haha nice typo catch, which means its my math now that is messed up =D

Comment: There's an easier way to achieve the desired effect http://jsfiddle.net/91mrzubh/ (probably even easier with rotation matrices).

Comment: Well now im disappointed in myself Alexey =(, thx haha

Comment: Also check out built-in matrix manipulation functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Transformations And here's how they can be applied to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/twja15kd/

Answer (score 0):

They work great, but you miss a point. (and the x4).

```
   x1 = (x1 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y1);
   y1 = (x1 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y1);
   x2 = (x2 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y2);
   y2 = (x2 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y2);
   x3 = (x3 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);
   y3 = (x3 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);
```

you update the value of `x1`, `x2`, `x3` but using it again just after.

you have to use same buffer, down your math and updates the values like:

```
var x1_ = (x1 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y1),
    y1_ = (x1 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y1),
    x2_ = (x2 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y2),
    y2_ = (x2 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y2),
    x3_ = (x3 * Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) - ((Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3),
    y3_ = (x3 * Math.sin(-(1/6)*Math.PI)) + ((Math.cos(-(1/6)*Math.PI))*y3);

x1 = x1_;
x2 = x2_;
x3 = x3_;
y1 = y1_;
y2 = y2_;
y3 = y3_;
```

Comment: I see what you are saying here, but why does it start where it is and then instantly move to the upper left, and then perfectly rotate there?

Comment: After moving upper left they doesn't rotate perfectly, they rotate but it is distorted.